# Spring metrics don't show Guava hit/miss

Tags: spring, google-guava-cache

In the metrics endpoint I get all the caches size, but not hit/miss (as expected from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-datasource-cache)

Example:
"cache.mytest.size":19

I expected also the hit/miss counters...
I'm using Guava.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to enable them on a per-cache basis:

https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#statistics

```
cacheBuilder.recordStats();
```